# pyramid with the word received in python

Tags: python

Could someone explain why this error appears? the program asks for a word, and makes a pyramid with the word.

```
palavra = input('Digite a palavra:').upper()
lista = list(palavra)
x = 0 #ímpares
y = 0 #contador
z = len(palavra) #conta o numero de letras mais o add

while y < z:
    if (x%2) == 0:
        x += 1
    else:
        p = lista[y]*x
        print(p.rjust(z))
        x += 1
        y += 1
        z += 1
```

Comment: Explain for a given input what happens, what should happen (show output and expected output as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: Why *what* error appears?

Comment: Since `y` and `z` are changed in lock-step, once you enter the loop, it will never end.

Comment: Loop never ends both the y and z value increaing. which cause index list out of range

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would've been good to change the variable names / comments to english so we can understand it easier

Answer (score 2):

I think z shouldn't be increased in the while loop other wise you will never end the while loop

```
palavra = input('Digite a palavra:').upper()
lista = list(palavra)
x = 0 #ímpares
y = 0 #contador
z = len(palavra) #conta o numero de letras mais o add

while y < z:
    if (x%2) == 0:
        x += 1
    else:
        p = lista[y]*x
        print(p.rjust(z))
        x += 1
        y += 1
        # z += 1
```

Comment: Commenting z cause spacing issue in pyramid

Answer (score 0):

**This will fix your error. Try this,**

```
palavra = input('Digite a palavra:').upper()
lista = list(palavra)
print(lista)
x = 0 #ímpares
y = 0 #contador
z = len(palavra) #conta o numero de letras mais o add

while y < z:
    if (x%2) == 0:
        x += 1
    else:
        if(len(palavra)-1 < y):  #Check the length of string and y value to end the loop
            break
    
        p = lista[y]*x
        print(p.rjust(z))
        x += 1
        y += 1
        z += 1
```

Output like this,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing 'y' in  iteration & that's make the issue. And the last iteration the it will always pointing to length of the string and list index   on that time doesn't exist

```
 palavra = input('Digite a palavra:').upper()
 lista = list(palavra)
 x = 0 #ímpares
 y = 0 #contador
 z = len(palavra) #conta o numero de letras mais o add
 strlen = len(palavra) #conta o numero de letras mais o a

while y < strlen:
  if (x%2) == 0:
    x += 1
  else:
    p = lista[y]*x
    print(p.rjust(z))
    x += 1
    y += 1
    z += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
palavra = input('Digite a palavra:').upper()
lista = list(palavra)
x = 0 #ímpares
y = 0 #contador
z = len(palavra) #conta o numero de letras mais o add
try:
 while y < z:
    if (x%2) == 0:
        x += 1
    else:
        p = lista[y]*x
        print(p.rjust(z))
        x += 1
        y += 1
        z += 1
except:
  pass

#output

Digite a palavra:Talha
    T
   AAA
  LLLLL
 HHHHHHH
AAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: It is all your code; just with a try-except block

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ineffiecient and not working properly.

The first thing to do is to use functions, so that you can reuse your code.

The second thing you should do is to use `str.center` method.

The mathematical relationship between the indices and the strings is that each string has the length of its index times two (0 based indexing).

So I reimplemented your code:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase

def pyramidize(s):
    l = (len(s) - 1) * 2 + 1
    return '\n'.join([(c * (i * 2 + 1)).center(l) for i, c in enumerate(s)])
    
print(pyramidize(ascii_lowercase))
```

```
                         a                         
                        bbb                        
                       ccccc                       
                      ddddddd                      
                     eeeeeeeee                     
                    fffffffffff                    
                   ggggggggggggg                   
                  hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh                  
                 iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii                 
                jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj                
               kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk               
              lllllllllllllllllllllll              
             mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm             
            nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn            
           ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo           
          ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp          
         qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq         
        rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr        
       sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss       
      ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt      
     uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu     
    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
   wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww   
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```